# Express js and Php Function

Tags: javascript, php, html, mongodb, express

I'm working on a project that uses expressjs, Php, Html and MongoDB

I have this code in my   "Index.Html"   File

```
<form action="/Login" method="POST">
  <input type="text" placeholder="name" name="Username">
  <input type="Password" placeholder="Password" name="Password">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I have this code in my   "Server.js"   File (Expressjs)

```
app.post('/Login', (req, res) => {
   //to know that I really had recieve a data from my index.html 
   console.log(req.body)
   //to collect data from my database (MongoDB)
   db.collection('User').find(req.body,{Username:"",password:""}).toArray(function(err, results) {
   //show result from the database
   console.log(results)

    //The Question Starts here. 
  })
})
```

How can I send both of those data (req.body and result) to my php file? so I can Validate it.
and also how can I send the data back from the PhP back to the server so the server could send the data back to the client?

Comment: just `res.write()` and `res.end()` ?

Comment: Are you trying to make a request to a PHP server?  Or run just run a PHP script?  It is not clear how the PHP fits into this.

Comment: run a php Script that is on a different file let's just call it "login.php"

Comment: You can use `child_process.exec()` to run your PHP script from node.js.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) to post a request to a php server. Example from the docs:

```
fetch('flowers.jpg')
.then(function(response) {
  return response.blob();
})
.then(function(myBlob) {
  var objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(myBlob);
  myImage.src = objectURL;
});
```